# How to access nested bigquery attributes?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to access a particular user property called "profileKey", and I want to get all events for the user with a certain profile key.

I tried doing the following

select * from this_table where user_properties.key.profileKey = 'someValue'

[image]

Comment: You'll need to `UNNEST()` the fields, can you share more detail on the error you got when you ran your query?

Comment: @BenP: this is what I tried

`select * from this_table where (user_properties.key = 'profileKey') AND (user_properties.value.string_value = 'this_value')`

The error was:
`Cannot access field key on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [1:105]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.this_table` t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM t.user_properties 
  WHERE (key, value.string_value) = ('profileKey', 'someValue')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how would you regex inside someValue?

For example, if we wanted to say something like: somethingLikethisString?

Comment: Your original question is answered fully. Please consider voting up! for any new / follow up questions  - just post new question with all relevant details and we will be happy too answer